# Number of days in a daterange

Tags: postgresql

How do you extract the number of days from a column of type `daterange`? Is it possible?

I tried

```
select age(daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01'));
```

But it fails, I also tried casting to `int` with out luck. I reviewed the docs but I was unable to find any function that could acomplish this in the range types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try using the `upper()` and `lower()` functions to find the upper and lower bound of the date range.  Then, take the difference of these dates to find the number of days in between them:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01')) -
        LOWER(daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01')) AS diff;

31
```

Note that the way you constructed your range is actually identical to this:

```
daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '[)')
```

That is, the range is upper bound exclusive.  As a result, only the 31 days of January 2018 are included in the count, but 1st February is excluded.  If you instead wanted to include that date point as well, you could use this range:

```
daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '[]')
```

Running the above query would then yield a day count of 32.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', '2018-01-01'::timestamp - '2018-02-01'::timestamp);
```

[EDIT]

using `daterange`, this will work:

```
SELECT upper(daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01')) - lower(daterange('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01'))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to get this answer using a date range directly.

Comment: That's true, I am looking for the answer (if exists) using `daterange`

Comment: I see that Biegeleisen has given the appropriate answer already.