# Is it possible with SQL to count all dateranges per year?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I select some dateranges with tsrange that includes a specific year.

I recieve an output like this:

```
  { time_range: '("2024-12-27 00:00:00","2025-02-01 00:00:00")' },
  { time_range: '("2025-05-01 00:00:00","2025-05-05 00:00:00")' },
  { time_range: '("2025-05-08 00:00:00","2025-05-20 00:00:00")' }
```

can I count all days grouped by year ?

currentcode:

```
SELECT time_range FROM holidays WHERE time_range && tsrange($1, $2, '[)')
```

Comment: What is your expected output for this count?  `3` because you have 3 time_range's, or `1` because they all connect... ?

Comment: Do you really have a string around the tupel?

Comment: @Luuk I want the count how many days are in 2024 and how many days are in 2025

Comment: OK, so you want something like `2024 | 5` because in 2024 you have 2024-12-17 .. 2024-12-31 And in 2025 a bigger number with 2025-01-01 .. 2025-02-01 (exclusive) and the length of the two other ranges?
I don't see how your current query has anything to do with that though.

Comment: You can start here: [Number of days in a daterange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286752/number-of-days-in-a-daterange)

Comment: @RichardHuxton yes I tried some other queries but all not worked so I didnt posted here

Comment: @RichardHuxton *"something like `2024 | 5` because in 2024 you have 2024-12-17 .. 2024-12-31"* - huh, isn't there like 15 days (inclusive)?

Comment: typo in my comment - 27th December in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to want a tsrange but rather a daterange. Otherwise I've kept your sample data. The series of CTE clauses are just to make it easier to read - you might want to merge some steps.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE src (
    id            int PRIMARY KEY
    , event_range daterange NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO src VALUES
    ( 1, '(2024-12-27,2025-02-01)' )
  , ( 2, '(2025-05-01,2025-05-05)' )
  , ( 3, '(2025-05-08,2025-05-20)' )
;

WITH target_years (y) AS (
    VALUES (2024), (2025), (2026)
)
, year_ranges (y, y_r) AS (
    SELECT y, daterange( make_date(y, 1, 1), make_date(y+1, 1, 1), '[)' )
    FROM target_years
)
, overlapping_ranges (y, o_r) AS (
    SELECT
        year_ranges.y
      , year_ranges.y_r * src.event_range AS o_r
    FROM
        year_ranges
        JOIN src    ON year_ranges.y_r && src.event_range
)
, range_day_counts AS (
    SELECT
        y
        , upper(o_r) - lower(o_r) AS days
    FROM
        overlapping_ranges
)
SELECT y, sum(days) AS tot_days
FROM range_day_counts
GROUP BY y
ORDER BY y
;
```

gives

```
  y   | tot_days 
------+----------
 2024 |        4
 2025 |       45
(2 rows)
```

Comment: How can I filter by user_id ? So where user_id = 4 then I get column user_id does not exists

Comment: You need to have a column called `user_id` to filter by it. There is no such column in the question.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that I assume that the provided date-ranges don't overlap each other. They don't in your example data.

Comment: You did it very good and thanks for prevent overlaping you are the best!. I did it on a other query for checking overlaping. I have to learn more sql but for the case of user_id I tried to add the user_id but I got error: column reference "o_r" is ambiguous, I tried on every cte or others but everytime I got error when I want to filter by user_id

Comment: Assuming `user_id` is on your source table add a `WHERE` clause in the `overlapping_ranges` CTE. At some point you are going to have to learn a little bit more SQL though if you are struggling with basic problems like building a where clause.

Answer (score 2):

using this data:

```
create table example (
  x int,
  ts tsrange);
INSERT INTO example VALUES
  (1, '[2024-12-27 00:00:00,2025-02-01 00:00:00)'),
  (2, '[2025-05-01 00:00:00,2025-05-05 00:00:00)'),
  (3, '[2025-05-08 00:00:00,2025-05-20 00:00:00)');
```

You can write a query which gets all dates in the range, and then count them.

```
WITH RECURSIVE days as (
  SELECT 
    x, 
    LOWER(ts) as t 
  FROM example 
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT 
    x, 
    t+'1 day' 
  FROM days 
  where t < (SELECT UPPER(ts) FROM example where x=days.x)
  )
SELECT 
  extract(year from t), count(*)
FROM days
GROUP BY extract(year from t)
ORDER BY extract(year from t)
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/t3QKtkcW)

output:

| year | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2024 | 5 |
| 2025 | 50 |

or, when you want them per daterange: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y8mrAxVp)

output:

| x | extract | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024 | 5 |
| 1 | 2025 | 32 |
| 2 | 2025 | 5 |
| 3 | 2025 | 13 |

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate the dates in each range with [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)
2. Don't ignore bound inclusivity
3. Count only distinct dates because ranges could overlap
4. Group by the year part

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xh836KcN)

```sql
SELECT date_part('year',holidate) "year", count(distinct holidate)
FROM holidays CROSS JOIN
generate_series( +(not lower_inc(time_range))::int+lower(time_range)::date
                ,-(not upper_inc(time_range))::int+upper(time_range)::date
                ,'1 day')as a(holidate)
WHERE holidate <@ tstzrange('2024-12-27', '2025-05-20', '[)')
GROUP BY "year";
```

| year | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2024 | 4 |
| 2025 | 45 |

If you want to prevent overlapping ranges, add an [exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) constraint:

```sql
alter table holidays add constraint non_overlapping_ranges 
  exclude using gist(time_range with &&);
```

Comment: The approach that uses only range bounds *would* perform better, but to get valid results you need to `range_agg()` then `unnest()` to merge overlapping ranges, then split those on Jan 1st so that they're fully contained in a given year, and only then grab a `sum(upper()-lower())`.

Comment: Thank you for the query I tried and it worked. How should I set my index on this case ?

Comment: @serverz If you decide to add the constraint, you don't need to add it: [it'll be added automatically to enforce the constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78116451/postgresql-do-i-have-to-create-an-index-or-is-that-already-an-index/78116832#78116832). Otherwise, add `create index on holidays using gist (time_range);` - but keep in mind that if you do allow overlaps in those ranges, this answer is the only one that gives you valid results.

Comment: I created an index with exlucude using gist (user_id WITH =, time_range = &&) or like that. I also check before I execute the query if the dates that the user send are overlaping else I dont run your query. So I make overlap checking but in another query

Comment: @serverz Sounds good. If overlaps are both prevented by a constraint and also stopped in their tracks in a separate check, then `upper()`-`lower()` (without actually spawning the dates just to count them) will be faster.

Comment: Nice do you have an example how can I only use upper/lower ?

Answer (score 0):

See example.
Whether or not to include boundary dates in the calculation is an open question. For example ('2024-03-14', '2024-03-15') =0? =1? or =2  ?

Sample data

```
create table holidays (id int, date_range tsrange);
insert into holidays values
 (1,'("2024-12-27 00:00:00","2025-02-01 00:00:00")' )
,(2,'("2025-05-01 00:00:00","2025-05-05 00:00:00")' )
,(3,'("2025-05-08 00:00:00","2025-05-20 00:00:00")' )
;
```

Query

```
with cte1 as(
  select *
    ,case when date_part('year',upper(date_range))<>date_part('year',lower(date_range)) 
         then 1
     else 0
     end overyear
  from holidays
)
,cte2 as(
select * 
  ,lower(date_range) l
  ,upper(date_range) u
  ,date_part('day',upper(date_range)- lower(date_range)) d
  ,case when n=0 then date_part('year',lower(date_range))
   else date_part('year',upper(date_range))
   end yy
  ,case when overyear>0 and n=0 then
           date_part('day',date_trunc('year',upper(date_range))-lower(date_range))
        when overyear>0 and n=1 then 
           date_part('day',upper(date_range)-date_trunc('year',upper(date_range)))
   else date_part('day',upper(date_range)- lower(date_range))
   end lng
from cte1
left join (values (0),(1))t(n)
  on n<=overyear
)
--select * from cte2;
select yy,sum(lng)lng
from cte2
group by yy
order by yy
;
```

Output

| yy | lng |
| --- | --- |
| 2024 | 5 |
| 2025 | 47 |

Subquery result is

| id | date_range | overyear | n | l | u | d | yy | lng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ("2024-12-27 00:00:00","2025-02-01 00:00:00") | 1 | 0 | 2024-12-27 00:00:00 | 2025-02-01 00:00:00 | 36 | 2024 | 5 |
| 1 | ("2024-12-27 00:00:00","2025-02-01 00:00:00") | 1 | 1 | 2024-12-27 00:00:00 | 2025-02-01 00:00:00 | 36 | 2025 | 31 |
| 2 | ("2025-05-01 00:00:00","2025-05-05 00:00:00") | 0 | 0 | 2025-05-01 00:00:00 | 2025-05-05 00:00:00 | 4 | 2025 | 4 |
| 3 | ("2025-05-08 00:00:00","2025-05-20 00:00:00") | 0 | 0 | 2025-05-08 00:00:00 | 2025-05-20 00:00:00 | 12 | 2025 | 12 |

Comment: There is no question as to whether the date-ranges are inclusive or exclusive. PostgreSQL defaults to (inclusive,exclusive) but allows you to specify exactly what you want.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY

Comment: Yes, the example shows the exclusion of boundaries. However, for the holidays it would be better to include borders:)